# Complex problem in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have a problem that has been consuming me for days.

I have a div and the div has a style for it to be hidden ( `.copy { display: none; }` ).

I have a link (Add new) that when clicked, makes a clone of that div and removes the class "copy", causing the div to appear.

Inside this div, I have 4 checkbox and a text input. Clicking this checkbox, the values are displayed in this input text.

When I click once on "Add New", he makes sure, but if I click a second time on the link "Add New" it shows all the checkbox values in the second input of the div, if I click again on "Add New" he starts to put the values in the input of the third div ...

It's complicated to explain, I do not know if I'm being clear, but put the example in jsbin http://jsbin.com/eteyu3.

See:

Click the "Add New" only once and then click the checkbox. Then click "Add New" again and see that it stops working right.

I wish he would just show the values of the div corresponding checkbox.

Comment: You have multiple instances of the same ID, name, etc. There's confusion as to where the numbers should be displayed when the checkbox is clicked. Each set of checkboxes should be uniquely identified.

Comment: I see nothing which can't be solved during 30 minutes using Firebug. (or Dragonfly, or any other development tools on any other browser, even IE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/eteyu3/2

I changed it this way and it works now.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $current = jQuery(this);

  jQuery(".add_new").bind("click", function() {
    var copy = jQuery(".copy").clone().insertBefore(".copy").removeClass("none").removeClass("copy");
    jQuery("input:checkbox", copy).click(function() {
      var val = [];
      jQuery(':checkbox:checked', copy).each(function(i) {
        val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
      });

      jQuery(".resultfinal", copy).val ( val );
    });

    jQuery(".count").val( jQuery(".opt:not(.copy)").length );
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While i am on it to fix this... everyone might use this: http://jsfiddle.net/c8aHb/

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your example is contrived but your approach seems more complex that it needs to be. Irregardless, your problem is you are re-binding the click event for all checkboxes over and over which will cause multiple events to be fired. try

```
unbind('click').bind('click')
```

where you do the click binding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parent()` to find the div containing the clicked checkbox, and then search within that parent for the textbox you're trying to populate.

```
jQuery($seletor + ':checkbox').click(function()
{
  var val = [], $parent = jQuery(this).parent();
  $parent.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i)
  {
    val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
  });

  $parent.find(".resultfinal").val ( val );
});
```

You can also use `.live` instead of worrying about binding events when each checkbox is created.  Your code will boil down to:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  jQuery('div.opt :checkbox').live('click', function() {
    var val = [], $parent = jQuery(this).parent();
    $parent.find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
      val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
    });
    $parent.find('.resultfinal').val(val);
  });

  jQuery(".add_new").bind("click", function() {
    jQuery(".copy").clone().insertBefore(".copy").removeClass("none").removeClass("copy");
    jQuery(".count").val( parseInt(jQuery(".count").val()) + 1 );
  });  
});
```